# How to receive messages from a remote udp server using spring integration

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration-dsl

I have a remote server that's sends packets throught a UDP connection. I know the IP and port.

I want to connect this server to recieve the packets but i don't know how. And a want to use Spring integration dsl.

Thanks to everyone who can help me.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "connection" with UDP; packets are sent to and received from specific hosts/ports (or a multicast group) individually.

See the documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/ip.html#ip-intro for how to use Spring UDP adapters.

If you have more questions after reading it; I suggest you ask a new question with the configuration you have tried, and much more detail about what you need to do.